# Current date only display " mm/dd/yy " in nsdate format not convert to nsstring in swift

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift4

I have db field `NSDate` format, so I try to insert current date but it displays like this `"2018-04-18 12:19:24 +0000"` but don't want that `12:19:24 +0000` values only `"2018-04-18"` these three. Can I get these values without converting `date` to `string`?

Comment: are you using oracle?

Comment: sqlite database

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSDateFormatter. Convert the dates to required format and than insert the converted dates in the Database.

```
//Step 1: Convert the date to string
NSDateFormatter * formatter =  [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];

//Step 2: Convert the string to date in the req format
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MMM-dd"];
NSDate *reqDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: He has mentioned `without converting date to string`. Your dateFormat `yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss` for `"2018-04-18 12:19:24 +0000"` is also wrong .

Comment: Thanks @TheTiger for pointing the mistake. I understand that he mentioned without converting to string but it's what he wants that DB don't accept string datatype for dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip the time portion with `startOfDay` of `Calendar`.

To get UTC create a custom calendar (here `gregorian`) and set the `timeZone` to UTC

```
var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!
let dateWithoutTime = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
print(dateWithoutTime)
```

Comment: Your code comes 2018-04-23 "00:00:00 +0000" that timestamp values also, i want exact like this 2018-04-23

Comment: @senthil `Date` object can never be like `2018-04-23` it will print full value. It can only contains different components so that `0` means it doesn't contain this component.

Comment: *without converting date to string* it's impossible. `Date` is just a point in time (actually a wrapper of a `Double`). Well you could use `DateComponents`

Comment: @vadian Even its not possible after converting into string too because he is printing a `date` object. :)